# Kotlin-allopen for android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-allopen

Is it possible to use kotlin-allopen gradle plugin for android testing with mockito?

I've tried to add kotlin-allopen plugin to my build.gradle and define the annotation.

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'

   dependencies {
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

allOpen {
    annotation("com.mycompany.OpenForTest")
}
```

And these for annotation itself

```
annotation class OpenForTest
```

It's not working for me. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: What is the problem? Have you encountered some error or are you just asking if it can be done?

Comment: It simply does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.
Because it's a compiler plugin, you'll get all-open code after compilation.
So it should work with tests.
Don't worry.

Edit: according to the comment area, updating the kotlin plugin version seems work. Currently the newest version is `1.2.41`.

Comment: Sorry, but I've not managed to do it. Looks like it isn't intended to work with Android gradle plugin, but it is not clearly stated anywhere in the docs. Or at least I haven't managed to find it.

Comment: It's OK, and currently the newest version is `1.1.3-2`. Maybe update again?

Comment: BTW the newest now is `1.2.0` :D

Comment: I am getting the same issues.  Does not appear to be working.  I am using Kotlin version 1.3.41 and the same version of the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

First add the dependency in your build.gradle (project) file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

After that apply the plugin in your build.gradle (app mobdule) file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
```

Then specify the list of annotations that will make classes open:

```
allOpen {
    annotation('com.example.myproject.OpenForTesting')
}
```

And use this annotation for every class which you want to be open

```
@OpenForTesting
```

Here is the Kotlin official documentation about All-open: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Hope this help

Comment: @MrVasiliev, can you tell me why my plugin usage is not working please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025359/how-to-enable-allopen-plugin-for-android

Comment: @LenaBru did you check the path to your OpenForTesting file in the build.gradle file -> "annotation('com.example.myproject.OpenForTesting')" ?